# Load more in php mysql and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to provide option to load more post in php webpage for my school project.

**Here are some of the php code.**

```
    <?php
        $prj= mysql_query("select * from campaign where uid=$uid order by Closing_Date DESC Limit 0,1");
            $record = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($prj)){
            $record[] = $row;
            }
     foreach($record as $rec){

                <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4" id="<?php echo $rec['cid'];?>">
                    <div class="well">
                        <div class="media services-wrap55 wow fadeInDown">

                                <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $rec['Project_Name'];?></h4></a>
                                <p> by <i><?php echo $rec['user_name'];?></i></p>
                                            <p> <?php echo $rec['short_dis'];?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    ?>

<?php } ?>

<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-12">
    <div class="media services-wrap55 wow fadeInDown"> 
        <center><h3 class="media-heading"><div class="more" id="more">Load More Post</div></h3></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is javascript code.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#more').click(function(){

        var get_last_post_display=$('li:last').attr('id'); //get ip last <li>

        $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif");
            $.ajax({                
                type: "POST",
                url: "more_prj.php",
                data: "last_id_post="+get_last_post_display, //send id ip last <li> to more_post.php
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){

                    $('ul').append(html);

                    $('#more').text('Load More Project'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again

                    if(!html){

                    $('#more').text('No more Project to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
                    }                   
                }
                });
        });                 
});
```

I have problem while configuring javascript below code. 
var get_last_post_display=$('li:last').attr('id');
It is configured for **li**  and i want to configure it for **div**.
I tried multiple times but no luck as i am not good with javascript.

Can you please advise me how to configure it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a class name

```
var get_last_post_display=$('.col-sm-1.col-md-4:last').attr('id');
```

**UPDATE**
You can use json, because sometimes you can get 404 page or another content and it will cause a problem, with a json you can be sure, that you got the needed content.

more_prj.php

```
<?php
$prj = mysql_query("select * from campaign where uid=$uid order by Closing_Date DESC Limit 0,1");
$result = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($prj)) {
    $result .= '<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4 unique-class" id="'.$row['cid'].'">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="media services-wrap55 wow fadeInDown">
                <h4 class="media-heading">'.$rec['Project_Name'].'</h4></a>
                <p> by <i>'.$rec['user_name'].'</i></p>
                <p>'.$rec['short_dis'].'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
}

//if($result) maybe some condition to check if you have any data?
$result .= 
'<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-12">
    <div class="media services-wrap55 wow fadeInDown"> 
        <center><h3 class="media-heading"><div class="more" id="more">Load More Post</div></h3></center>
    </div>
</div>';

echo json_encode($result);
```

js script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var get_last_post_display = $('.unique-class:last').attr('id'); //get ip last <li>
        $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"');
        $.post('more_prj.php', 'last_id_post='+get_last_post_display, function(html) {
            if(html) {
                $('div').append(html);//$('.main-div') ?
                $('#more').text('Load More Project'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again
            } else {
                $('#more').text('No more Project to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: i have multiple div with col-sm-1 on the page. is there anything i can do to fix conflict.

Comment: use a unique class name, for example <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-4 unique"> and $(".unique:last").attr("id")

Comment: or add data tag like <div data-id="post"> $('[data-id="post"]:last').attr('id')

Comment: check my update, maybe it will help you, thank you )

Comment: thanks. If there is an option to vote twice then i will did that. :) Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: i have 2 php file. 1 index.php (code given above) 2. more_prj.php. You have given some code in the answer. where do i need to put that php code. confused between two files.

Comment: your js code posts a query to more_prj.php file, so add it there, are index.php and more_prj.php the same?

Comment: no. more_prj code and index.php code are different. Default data is come from index after that when user click on load more then it fetch the data from more_prj.php file.

Comment: I am still trying to convert this code to use in my current php code. Actually you added all the html code in php under  $result var and i was adding php code in html like this <div name="<?php echo $abcd;?>">. So, it is taking much time to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81787/discussion-between-droid-and-404).

Comment: have you done it? sorry, got conection problems yesterday

Comment: yes i tried and it got fixed. However there are progress bar on the page and it is configured in javascript. This is not loading i am getting the value. So, will need to create another ajax script to get the data and update it on runtime.

Comment: ok, glad to hear that ) don't forget to escape string when using mysql query, to avoid sql injection.

Comment: sure i willl do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108035 check this question. you can understand better than others