# run javascript after loading data from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-countdown

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {

      var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');

      $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {

         $this.html('Time Left : '+ event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'))}).on('finish.countdown', function() {

            $this.html('This campaignn has expired!');

          });
     });
 });

</script>
```

This is javascript used to display countdown timer.
I am using **jquery.countdown.min.js** plugin.

```
<div class="counter-inner"> <div id="example<?php echo $rec['cid'];?>" data-countdown="<?php echo date("m/d/Y h:i:s", strtotime($rec['Closing_Date']));?>"></div></div><p>
```

Closing_Date and cid comes from database.
When i access it is working fine.

But when i insert data by ajax to index.php. it doesn't do anything. It seems like javascript code is not executed.

I checked in firebug and found date is coming to index.php file but it is not showing countdown timer.

Please advise

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#more').click(function() {
        var get_last_post_display = $('.unique-class:last').attr('id');

        $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"');
        $.post('more_prj.php', 'last_id_post='+get_last_post_display, function(html) {
            if(html) {

                $('#main-div').append(html);
                $('#more').text('Load More Post'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again
            } else {
                $('#more').text('No more Post to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: Re-run the `.each()` in your AJAX callback.

Comment: Can you show your AJAX call code?

Comment: move $('[data-countdown]').each(function() { code block after $('#main-div').append(html);

Comment: @droid i will update the above code in ajax. is there anything else to change?

Comment: It worked. Could you please paste it in answer? Thanks

Comment: Guys, thanks a ton for clearing my doubt. Now i understand how to insert javascript code in ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move $('[data-countdown]').each(function() to ajax js, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#more').click(function() {
    var get_last_post_display = $('.unique-class:last').attr('id');

    $('#more').html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"');
    $.post('more_prj.php', 'last_id_post='+get_last_post_display, function(html) {
        if(html) {
            $('#main-div').append(html);
            $('#more').text('Load More Post'); //add text "Load More Post" to button again
            $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
                $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
                $this.html('Time Left : '+ event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'))}).on('finish.countdown', function() {
                    $this.html('This campaignn has expired!');
                });
            });
        } else {
            $('#more').text('No more Post to load'); // when last record add text "No more posts to load" to button.
        }
    }, 'json');
  });
});
```