# Load More content from database

Tags: php, ajax

i'm trying to create a load more button to load more comments from database. Firstly i want to limit only 4 comments to be displayed and the rest to be loaded when click on load more button. I tried to find a solution online but I'm not able to fit it with my code... please help! I admit that I am very bad at php

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

    <?php

    // //fetch_comment.php

    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');


    // select from DB

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM comments 
    WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' 
    ORDER BY comment_id LIMIT 4
    ";



    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';


    foreach($result as $row)
    {
     $output .= '
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Par <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
      <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
      <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;"class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
     </div>

     ';


     
     $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"]);
    }



    echo $output;

    function get_reply_comment($connect, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0)
    {
     $query = "
     SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'
     ";
     $output = '';
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     $result = $statement->fetchAll();
     $count = $statement->rowCount();
     if($parent_id == 0)
     {
      $marginleft = 0;
     }
     else
     {
      $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
     }
     if($count > 0)
     {
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
       $output .= '
       <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:'.$marginleft.'px">
        <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
        <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
        <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
       </div>

       
       ';
       
       $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);


     
      }

      

     }

     
     return $output;
    }

    ?>



<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <section class="comments-section" id="comments">

      <div class="container">


        <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom ou pseudo" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea style="resize: none;" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Redigez votre commentaire" maxlength="1000" rows="6"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publier" />
          </div>
        </form>
        <span id="comment_message"></span>
        <br />



        <div id="display_comment"></div>

        <button class="loadmore">Load More</button>

    </section>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: use offset in you query and set $limit =  4. where ever the offset is clicked its value should increase by $limit as well. your query should look like "Select * from TableName limit $offset,$limit; Then append the new data in the end.

Comment: Offset can be very performance heavy since it loads all the rows until the end and then throws away all the rows that are not needed because of the offset.

Comment: Please can you explain me how to append the new data? Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load more in php mysql and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099425/load-more-in-php-mysql-and-jquery)

Comment: You can set the last comment_id as the value of the button and modify the query to [ WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' and comment_id > $lastID limit 4;
Use jQuery or ajax to append the result to the previous Tags.